# tmux + iTerm2 - no permission to edit crontab

Tags: permission, iterm, tmux, cron

I am running macOS 10.14.5, iTerm2 build 3.2.8,  tmux 2.9a (`tmux -V`).

I've granted both `iTerm2.app` and `Terminal.app` (file permission: `.r-xr-xr-x`) **Full Disk Access** (FDP) in Sys prefs > Security and Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access.

Now I am able to edit crontab using `crontab -e` in iTerm2 if I am **not** attached to a tmux session.
But I still don't have the permission to edit crontab in tmux in iTerm2 (which I can in `Terminal.app`) even if I use
`sudo crontab -u username -e`.

Error message:

```
$ crontab -e

crontab: installing new crontab
crontab: tmp/tmp.43698: Operation not permitted
crontab: edits left in /tmp/crontab.bytUnVCVVk
```

So is there anyway I can edit crontab in tmux in iTerm2?

Edit: Yes, granting FDP for `tmux` is unnecessary.

Edit: Add the comparison between Terminal and iTerm2.

Comment: You shouldn't need to grant any special permissions to iTerm2 or `tmux` to edit the crontab with `crontab -e`. What's the specific error message you get trying to run `crontab -e` from the `tmux` session?

Comment: I think Full Disk Access is a must for macOS **Mojave**. Can't edit crontab and save without it.

Comment: Does it work if you use `Terminal.app` and not `iTerm2`?

Comment: @lan C. Yes. It works in tmux in Terminal.app, but not in iTerm2. Maybe there is some restriction user cannot go through?

Comment: on my machine it's just `iTerm.app`, not `iTerm2.app` (even though it is _iTerm2_). [I can confirm the Full Disk Access grant for iTerm2 is necessary](https://i.imgur.com/pPih1H1.png), no need to do anything for `tmux` though. Are you certain you granted access to the correct program? Maybe we can take this to chat?

Comment: @IanC. Thank you for your info! which macOS version are you using?

Comment: I'm on `10.14.5`

Comment: It seems like you didn't have permission to write temporary files in /tmp folder. Please run commands with `ls -alH /tmp` and `whoami` respectively and show me the output.